# RequireJS always looking for jquery in the root

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I am  using jquery with requirejs using the following folder structure:

```
app.js
/app/[my modules].js
/scripts/jquery.min.js
/scripts/require.min.js
```

The jquery pertenant bits of my config in app.js are as follows:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/",
    paths: {
        'jquery': "scripts/jquery.min",
        'Bootstrap': "scripts/bootstrap.min",
        'Sammy': "scripts/sammy.min",
    },
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: "jQuery"
        },
        Bootstrap: {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        },
        Sammy: {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        }
    }
});
```

Modules in /app that use it simply reference it like:

```
define(["jquery"],function() { ... });
```

When I run this, I get a 404 error however with requirejs looking for jquery in the root (same level as app.js). It seems no matter what I do in my modules or in the config, it looks for jquery at the same level as app.js. I was able to get everything working by just moving jquery.js into the root, but that is obviously not an acceptable solution to the problem.

I found all kinds of information talking about using "jquery" all lower case. which I am doing. But strangely enough, it is actually looking for "jQuery.js" in the root.

Comment: Have you tried changing your `baseUrl` to `scripts/`?

Comment: Not yet, I have my custom scripts in /app though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem, I just gave up too soon and posted my question lol. Sorry for wasting everyones time, but I do appreciate the quick responses!

Turns out I had a third party amd module reference pointing to "jQuery" in my scripts folder. Once I removed that everything started working. It wasn't all a waste of time though. Trying to figure out this incredibly stupid problem turned out to be an extremely informative journey into the inner workings of requirejs! :D

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to shim jquery

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/",
    paths: {
        'jquery': "scripts/jquery.min",
        'Bootstrap': "scripts/bootstrap.min",
        'Sammy': "scripts/sammy.min",
    },
    shim: {
        Bootstrap: {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        },
        Sammy: {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: yea I read that somewhere and tried removing it, didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Can you load jquery from CDN //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min